# Draw on a part of a context?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, cgcontext

Is it possible by using UIGraphicsBeginImageContext to draw CGImage in a region of image context of my CGImage?

Example: I have image context 100x100 and i want to draw CGImage in a coordinates (x:4, y:0) and with width 50.
I'm trying to do it by

```
CGContextDrawImage(fullContext, CGRect(x: 4, y: 0, width: 50,     
height: size.height), tiledBackground.CGImage);
```

But device always draws tiledBackground.CGImage from (4.0) till (100,0) repeating CGImage ignoring my width argument.